# Passing props in react, image src not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm storing the image src and alt in an array of objects. I'm passing each object as prop.

```
import React from 'react'
import { ImageBlock } from '../components/ImageBlock'

const LandingPage = () => {

    const imageBlocks = [
        {
            src: "../assets/images/mobile/image-transform.jpg",
            alt: "transform"
        },
        {
            src: "../assets/images/mobile/image-stand-out.jpg",
            alt: "stand out"
        },
        {
            src: "../assets/images/mobile/image-graphic-design.jpg",
            alt: "graphic design"
        },
        {
            src: "../assets/images/mobile/image-photography.jpg",
            alt: "photography"
        }
    ]

    return (
        <div className="l-home-wrapper">
   
            <ImageBlock image={imageBlocks[0]}/>
     
        </div>
    )
}

export default LandingPage
```

Then I'm trying to reference it in the ImageBlock component

```
import React from 'react'

export const ImageBlock = (props) => {
    const image = props.image
    return (
        <img className="c-image-block" src={image.src} alt={image.alt}/>
    )
}
```

It's not working. I have console logged const image and the directory comes through.

Comment: Maybe `src` does not match. check it carefully

Answer (score 1):

Can you please do the following. Please make sure imported images are in the correct directory.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ImageBlock } from '../components/ImageBlock';
import imageTransform from '../assets/images/mobile/image-transform.jpg';
import imageStandOut from '../assets/images/mobile/image-stand-out.jpg';
import imageGraphic from '../assets/images/mobile/image-graphic-design.jpg';
import imagePhoto from '../assets/images/mobile/image-photography.jpg';

const LandingPage = () => {

    const imageBlocks = [
        {
            src: imageTransform,
            alt: "transform"
        },
        {
            src: imageStandOut,
            alt: "stand out"
        },
        {
            src: imageGraphic,
            alt: "graphic design"
        },
        {
            src: imagePhoto,
            alt: "photography"
        }
    ]

    return (
        <div className="l-home-wrapper">
   
            <ImageBlock image={imageBlocks[0]}/>
     
        </div>
    )
}

export default LandingPage
```

And Then as you did

```
import React from 'react'

export const ImageBlock = (props) => {
    const image = props.image
    return (
        <img className="c-image-block" src={image.src} alt={image.alt}/>
    )
}
```

Comment: Importing directly works fine for me.

Comment: Great. If you want to use direct img path then you have to do it as following: <img src={require('./logo.jpeg')} />. You need to require.

Comment: This doesn't work. No error in console just shows image alt in browser.